# Getting the values at which a variable is split consecutively by a decision tree in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tree

I am using decision tree to split a single feature into segments having the Target as guide.

What I would like is to export the values at which the feature is split as a list or array.

For a reproducible example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()

target = iris.target

target[target == 2] = 0  # Convert to binary problem

clf_iris = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 3)

clf_iris.fit(iris.data[:, 3].reshape(-1,1), target) # Classify using only one feature

dot_data_iris = tree.export_graphviz(clf_iris, out_file=None,  
                         filled=True, rounded=True,  
                         special_characters=True)  

graph_iris = graphviz.Source(dot_data_iris)
```

[image]

In this example I would like to get a list/array with the numbers:

```
[0.8, 1.35, 1.75, 1.85]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get access to the "tree" by accessing the `.tree_` attribute of your model. Maybe try something like this:

```
print(dir(clf_iris.tree_))
print(clf_iris.tree_.threshold)
```

I think you're looking for the `.threshold` attribute, but as you can see there are also attributes like `.value` which might contain what you need.